# Why does DAO Recordset.Update to SharePoint list never complete?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

My Access VBA code does a DAO recordset.update agains a SharePoint list and Access just runs and runs. Here are some deatails ...

- All of the VBA code ran just fine for 4 years under SP 2010.
- We recently updated to SP 2013 and things broke. And by broke, I mean that the call to recordset.update never returns and never throws an error but Access continues to run.
- Yes, I updated the SP connections.
- The update is for a single record.
- The update doesn't hang-up if no fields have changed in the record.
- When I look at Windows' TaskManger the ACCESS process is maxed out at 25% utilization on a quad core processor. The quantity of memory utilized occansionaly changes value.

Thanks,
Mark

z3419

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access menu, set Options --> Current Database --> "Use the cache format tat is compatible with Microsoft Access 2010 and later". Unset the following two sub-items: Clear Cache on Close AND Never Cache. See http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=214875 for discussion.

-Mark